# Using UpdateByQueryRequest in java client

Tags: java, elasticsearch, update-by-query

I am trying to use `UpdateByQueryRequest` in java. The problem is, I am getting different syntax suggestion in `eclipse`. I am using `java RestHighLevelClient`. Here is an example

```
import org.elasticsearch.index.reindex.UpdateByQueryRequest;
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(index).types(type);
```

There are 2 suggestions I am getting. First one is **without** `SearchRequest` object and second one is **with** `SearchRequest` object

```
UpdateByQueryRequest updateByQueryRequest = new UpdateByQueryRequest();
UpdateByQueryRequest updateByQueryRequest = new UpdateByQueryRequest(searchRequest);
```

I am unable to use `setQuery` like used everywhere else in ES. On the other hand `setScript` works

```
updateByQueryRequest.setQuery()
```

Is there some other syntax to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the internal implementation of setQuery():

```
public UpdateByQueryRequest setQuery(QueryBuilder query) {
  if (query != null) {
    this.getSearchRequest().source().query(query);
  }

  return this;
}
```

Your final code will look like this:

```
UpdateByQueryRequest updateByQueryRequest = new UpdateByQueryRequest(searchRequest);
if (query != null) {
   updateByQueryRequest.getSearchRequest().source().query(query);
}
```

If you don't have access to updateByQueryRequest.getSearchRequest(), maybe the problem is in the library or your IDE, you can try to decompile the class and check if the method exists (ElasticSearch is open source, so it won't be a possible legal problem), also I recommend you to upload the library or download it again and check if the problem persists.